# discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import guild
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';', case_insensitive=True)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    print('Bot Online')

@slash.slash(
  name='Hi',
  description='Hi Command',
  guild_ids=[947837363529326623]
)
async def _hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
```

Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BotDiscord\virenv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py:416> exception=Forbidden('403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BotDiscord\virenv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 440, in sync_all_commands
existing_cmds = await self.req.get_all_commands(guild_id=scope)
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\BotDiscord\virenv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access

Comment: Can you share which line is 416

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not enable applications.build in the portal when inviting the bot. On top of enabling the bot, to create slash _commands you need to enable applications.build as well